# Validar dos campos en flutter usando bloc

Tags: flutter, validación, stream, bloc

Tengo un formulario en flutter que requiere email, password y confirmas pasword, encontré un solución aquí en stackoverflow pero no reconoce el método `doOnData()`

```
Stream<String> get repeatpasswordStream =>
  _repeatpasswordController.stream.transform(validarRepeatPassword)
  .doOnData(
    (String c) {
      if (0 != _passwordController.value.compareTo(c)) {
        _repeatpasswordController.addError("No Match");
      }
    },
  );
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es validar tus campos con patrón bloc? o el paquete bloc?.

Comment: ya tienes instalado el paquete rxdart

Comment: y por tu codigo, este es el repositorio de donde esta tu ejemplo. https://github.com/boeledi/blocs

Answer (score 0):

Podrías quitar el doOnData y dejarlo así:

```
Stream<String> get repeatpasswordStream =>
_repeatpasswordController.stream.transform(validarRepeatPassword);
```

Por ejemplo este método para validar la longitud (aquí podrías usar otro método para validar)

```
final validarPassword = StreamTransformer<String,String>.fromHandlers(
handleData: (password,sink){

  if(password.length > 6 ){
    sink.add(password);
  }
  else{
    sink.addError('Más de 6 caracteres por favor');
  }
 }
);
```